# Multiple checkbox clicking is not working. it always clicking on first element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to click on Campus checkbox but its clicking on first checkbox only.

Below is the Code--

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/products/mens-footwear-sports-shoes");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button\[@data-filtername="Brand"\]")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div\[@class="brand-filter-columns"\]//div//label/a"));
System.out.println(list.size());
for (WebElement s : list) {
String text = s.getText();
System.out.println(text);

            if (text.contains("Campus"));
            {
                s.click();
                break;
            }
    
        }

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEiK5.png)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to be ok except for one small error of `;`

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/products/mens-footwear-sports-shoes");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button\[@data-filtername="Brand"\]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div\[@class="brand-filter-columns"\]//div//label/a"));
    System.out.println(list.size());
    for (WebElement s : list) {
        String text = s.getText();
        System.out.println(text);
    
        if (text.contains("Campus")) // ; I HAVE COMMENTED THIS SEMI-COLON WHICH IS CAUSING ERROR
         {
           s.click();
           break;
         }
        
    }
```

Please tell me if it works with this minor correction.

Comment: @ManojSingh Please be kind to **Upvote** and **Accept** the answer

Comment: See your Reputations? That's the power of **Upvote**